# Find the best matching combination of numbers

Tags: javascript, mathematics

I need to manipulate `chunks` `quantity` until total will be as close as possible to the `requirements`. Decimals are ok in the quantity.

Again: I can change only `quantity` property.

So if the requirements are {a:500; b:1200; c:1500}, then the `quantity` field in the `chunks` array should be changed so that when I run this:

```
// sum all chunks
Object.keys(chunks).forEach(chunk=> {
  Object.keys(total).forEach(id=> {
    total[id] += chunks[chunk].payload[id] * chunks[chunk].quantity
  });
```

It returns an object as close as possible to `{a:500; b:1200; c:1500}`.

How do I do that efficiently?

```js
const chunks = { // <- the chunks
  chunk1: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 19, b: 17, c: 10 } 
  },
  chunk2: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 17, b: 11, c: 15 } 
  },
  chunk3: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 7, b: 19, c: 0 } 
  },
  chunk4: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 14, b: 4, c: 19 } 
  },
  chunk5: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 3, b: 15, c: 6 } 
  },
  chunk6: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 10, b: 16, c: 3 } 
  },
  chunk7: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 2, b: 3, c: 2 } 
  },
  chunk8: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 14, b: 16, c: 11 } 
  },
  chunk9: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 7, b: 2, c: 2 } 
  },
  chunk10: {
    quantity: 0, // <- the quantity
    payload: { a: 1, b: 7, c: 17 }
  }
}

const requirements = { // <- the requirements
  a: 500,
  b: 1200,
  c: 1500
}

const total = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}

// sum all chunks
Object.keys(chunks).forEach(chunkId => {
  Object.keys(total).forEach(propId => {
    total[propId] += chunks[chunkId].payload[propId] * chunks[chunkId].quantity
  })
})

console.log(total) // <- i need this to be as close as possible to the `requirements`.

// MY SOLUTION:
const percentages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chunks))
Object.keys(percentages).forEach(chunkId => {
  let total = 0
  Object.keys(percentages[chunkId].payload).forEach(propId => {
    const perc =
      percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] / (requirements[propId] / 100)
    percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] = perc
    total += perc
  })
  Object.keys(percentages[chunkId].payload).forEach(propId => {
    percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] =
      percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] / (total / 100)
  })
})

const myTotal = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
}

Array.from(Array(10)).forEach(() => {
  Object.keys(percentages).forEach(chunkId => {
    let highestPropId
    let highestPropPercentage = 0
    Object.keys(percentages[chunkId].payload).forEach(propId => {
      const perc = percentages[chunkId].payload[propId]
      if (perc > highestPropPercentage) {
        highestPropPercentage = perc
        highestPropId = propId
      }
    })
    const remainingNum = requirements[highestPropId] - myTotal[highestPropId]
    const koe = 0.5
    const multiplier =
      (remainingNum / chunks[chunkId].payload[highestPropId]) * koe
    Object.keys(myTotal).forEach(propId => {
      myTotal[propId] += chunks[chunkId].payload[propId] * multiplier
    })
    chunks[chunkId].quantity += multiplier
  })
})

console.log('myTotal', myTotal)
/*
in the console log output you'll see this:
{
  "a": 499.98450790851257,
  "b": 1202.1742982865637,
  "c": 1499.5877967505367
}
compare it with the `requirements` object above:
const requirements = { // <- the requirements
  a: 500,
  b: 1200,
  c: 1500
}
as you see, it's almost the same. I need more efficient solution
*/
```

It's not accurate and quite inefficient. Any better options?

Notes, answering the first comment:

- Second snippet contains first snippet and my solution.
- The `quantity` is a property in `chunks` object. Find it in the very beginning of the first snippet
- "As close as possible" means as close to `requirements` as mathematically possible.
- Input is in the first code snippet. To get output, pls run the first snippet.

Comment: This is not a particularily bad question, but you might want to invest some more time to clarify the problem. Maybe explain how the first code snippet is related to the second one. Define what as close as possible mean. Define what manipulate quantity mean. Maybe show some example intput-output combinations, especialy one that would show an output that one might have not expected and explain why it should return that output rather than a different one.

Comment: @slepic alright, i've added answers to your questions

Comment: Sorry, but that did not help at all. You're gonna have to invest a bit more then 2 minutes and describe the problém as if to someone who knows nothing about it. And btw if the first snippet Is part of the second, then remove the first one, Its just confusing.

Comment: I read the question twice and still have no idea what the "requirements" are, as in how they relate to the `requirements` object.  Can't you share a way smaller example with just one requirement?

Comment: @slepic i've changed code snippet. I hope now everything i clear

Comment: @GirkovArpa requirements is the `requirements` object. I've changed the code snippet, hope now it's clear

Comment: Is the code allowed to have chunks with zero quantity?

Comment: I am trying very hard to understand what this question is asking us but it is still unclear what @stkvtflw goal is with this code

Comment: When running the code as is, I get negative values for the `quantity` of chunk 4, 6, 7, 8 and 9. It seems rather counterintuitive to me having negative quantities - which would mean, that I have to remove something from a total, that isn't really there to begin with. Or maybe the term `quantity` isn't the right/original name for the value?

Comment: Can `quantity` be 0 or negative?

Answer (score 5):

From a short review;

- Your code is really hard to read/parse, I would not want to maintain this
- You have no useful comments, `// <- the quantity` is not useful
- [You should terminate your lines with `;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171651/why-is-a-semicolon-required-at-end-of-line),
- I don't know if you have control over how you get the data, but getting it as an object is not helpful, this would be much easier/readable if you got a list instead
- In fact, this code is full of functional programming on objects, if you really want to do this, you should convert your objects to lists first
- `Array(10)` <- You hardcoded `10`, at least go for `Object.keys(chunks).length`
- `koe` is an unfortunate variable name, why is it 0.5? (See lack of comments)
- In a `solution` driven approach, you should probably never enumerate over the keys of the payload (`Object.keys(percentages[chunkId].payload).forEach`), the payload could have more fields than the solution
- This should be 1 line

  ```
  const perc =
    percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] / (requirements[propId] / 100)
  ```
- I see this as a [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is NP-hard, meaning that getting the perfect result will always be slow, in fact I see this as a multi-dimensional knapsack problem which is even harder than the regular knapsack problem.

From the comments, if we think of `(a,b,c)` as (length, width, height) and `requirements` as a bag of size (500, 1200, 1500). Then the question is how can we best (best as, least space wasted) fill the bag with different `chunks` (they all have their `size` defined in `payload`).

Comment: You describe it as a knapsack problem, implying you may have greater insight into what the poster is asking?  Could you elaborate?

Comment: "_You should terminate your lines with `;`_" I know why but others, especially the OP, likely don't - it would be good to provide an explanation, possibly with references

Comment: @GirkovArpa added more, let me know if not sufficient. Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ; fair point, updated my comment with a link

Comment: Ah!  I see what the OP is asking now.  If there were only a couple chunks, and `solution.a == 100`, and `chunk1.payload.a == 5` and `chunk2.payload.a == 15`, OP wants to know what to multiply `5` and `15` by so that when you sum them, they add up to `100`.  He calls this number `quantity`.  So `chunk1.quantity` would be `50` if `chunk2.quantity` is `1/3`.  Because `(5 * 10) + (15 * (1/3)) == 100`.

Comment: But the same `quantity` has to work for `chunk1.payload.a`, `chunk1.payload.b`, and `chunk1.payload.c`.

Comment: And maybe `quantity` should be as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace this entire block of code with `const percentages = chunks;` and your results more precisely match the requirements:

```
// MY SOLUTION:
const percentages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chunks))
Object.keys(percentages).forEach(chunkId => {
  let total = 0
  Object.keys(percentages[chunkId].payload).forEach(propId => {
    const perc =
      percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] / (requirements[propId] / 100)
    percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] = perc
    total += perc
  })
  Object.keys(percentages[chunkId].payload).forEach(propId => {
    percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] =
      percentages[chunkId].payload[propId] / (total / 100)
  })
})
```

```
myTotal { a: 500.3204153326983, b: 1200.0002333151795, c: 1499.7678177477337 }
```

Previously your result was:

```
myTotal { a: 499.98450790851257, b: 1202.1742982865637, c: 1499.5877967505367 }
```

For the record, I still have no idea what you're trying to do.

> manipulate chunks quantity until total will be as close as possible to the requirements

Then why not just add the difference so they are equal?